# Constraints not getting updated in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm working on a little app and trying to understand constraints better.

I just noticed that I have constraints on the left and selected 'width', and then the size inspector on the right for the same constraint.

[image]

[image]

What I'm seeing is that if I change the 'width = 100' value on the left, it doesn't update in the size inspector or the preview. And when I update it in the size inspector, it updates the preview but doesn't change the value on the left.

What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the so called "Document Outline" (on the left) you can give your constraints names that help you to identify them easier. they do not have to be in any special format. instead of **width = 100** you could simply call it **width constraint for my button**. to change the actual value use the size inspector on the right.

Comment: So, the 'width = 100' was just the default name xcode gave it when I created the constraint originally?

Comment: This is the most counterintuitive thing I've ever seen. I spent so much time trying to figure out why the layout was broken, and I just realized this. I submitted a Feedback from the apple website, to make this point clearer (maybe adding the constraint value inside parenthesis)